# PHP setcookie domain parameter

Tags: php, setcookie

I'd like to understand how does *domain* parameter of `setcookie` function works. I've the following code:

setcookie.php:

```
setcookie("cookie_4", "c4", time()+3600, "", "home_domain.com");
setcookie("cookie_5", "c5", time()+3600, "", "sub2.home_domain.com");
```

When i make the request form `http:\\home_domain.com\setcookie.php`
the ***cookie_4*** is available in both `http:\\home_domain.com\getcookie.php` and `http:\\sub2.home_domain.com\getcookie.php` requests but cookie ***cookie_5*** isn't available from `http:\\sub2.home_domain.com\getcookie.php` even if it's explicitly set  for domain ***sub2.home_domain.com***?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Windows 10, neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. What's your environment? Have you changed default cookie settings? Are you positively sure your verification is correct? [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/7kQzoJY.png)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, im on win10 64-bit, Firefox. I haven't changed any cookie settings and yes, I've checked it several times.

Comment: I suppose the names and values have been redacted and you possibly have additional code. It could really be anything: your company's security software filtering out HTTP headers for certain domains, some other piece of code that's overwriting some, a malformed string... To my knowledge, the code you've shared should work flawlessly.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  "the code you've shared should work flawlessly" - so You have _cookie_5_ set when making request _sub2.home_domain.com\getcookie.php_ after setting it by _home_domain.com\setcookie.php_?

Comment: Oh, my excuses, I misread your description. Setting a cookie for `sub2.home_domain.com` from `home_domain.com` is something you cannot do. There's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803192/13508) in the question linked by fraggley.